# Similarity in structure and their inner element layout

Tags: c, struct

Let's say we have a structure as follows (where T and U are any of the basic data types like int,long, char etc.)

```
struct S1 {
   T t1;
   U u1;
};
```

and another structure

```
struct S2 {
   T t2;
   U u2;
};
```

Now I allocate

```
struct S1* s1 = malloc(sizeof(*s1))
```

And with`container_of` defined as

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) \
    *__mptr = (ptr);
    (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

if I proceed to pass around `T* x`, the following could be done

```
struct S2* s2 = container_of(x, struct S2, t2)
//Here s2->u2 is the same value as that of s1->u1
```

Now my query is assuming that such operations occur oblivious to each other (in different libraries for eg.), this would lead to weird value modifications.

Context is:

I have my own code with S1, but when I pass t1 to another library code, that has another similar structure S2 and ends up modifying the value of u1 too. Is there any way to guard against such inadvertent use cases ? Also, let's say at each end of an interface, we have a `T* x` pointer, but both the interface implementer and the interface client for their usage purpose are storing it as part of structures S1 and S2. In that case too, the same situation may arise where mostly the server code would be unchangeable. How do we address this issue in those cases ?

A real example from the Kernel V4L2 framework [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.12/source/drivers/media/v4l2-core/videobuf2-v4l2.c#L188)

```
static void __fill_v4l2_buffer(struct vb2_buffer *vb, void *pb)
{
    struct v4l2_buffer *b = pb;
    struct vb2_v4l2_buffer *vbuf = to_vb2_v4l2_buffer(vb);
    :
    :
    b->flags = vbuf->flags;
```

Now I had allocated a structure as follows:

```
my_v4l2_driver_video_buf{
    struct vb2_buffer vb;
    dma_addr_t addr;
}
```

and here's the definition of `vb2_v4l2_buffer`

```
struct vb2_v4l2_buffer {
    struct vb2_buffer   vb2_buf;    
    __u32           flags;
    __u32           field;
    struct timeval      timestamp;
    struct v4l2_timecode    timecode;
    __u32           sequence;
};
```

> Note: dma_addr_t was 32bit too

And then I had passed pointer to `vb` to v4l2 framework. It modified the flags in the function `__fill_v4l2_buffer` and I ended up getting the `v4l2_buffer* b` 's flags set to the same `dma_addr_t addr` of my structure

Comment: Have you written up the question correctly? `container_of` appears to be an attempt to obtain the address of a structure given the address of one of its members, but the `x` you show is not a pointer to a `T` within an `S1`; it is a pointer to isolated space allocated for just a `T`, not enough for an `S1`.

Comment: Similar think happens when casting sockaddr to/from sockaddr_in. I would write a `static_assert(offset(struct S1, u1) == offset(struct S2, u2) && sizeof((struct S2*)0)->u1) == sizeof(((struct S1*)0)->u1), "");` As for handling different machines, have you taken endianess into account? Different compilers? Different number of padding bytes? IF you want to transfer such struct over a net/pipe to another program, just write a proper serialization functions and be 100% safe.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for pointing that out, I have corrected it to reflect that atleast one end needs to allocate a complete struct. Then passing around the pointer to the inner element is what my query seeks to resolve.

Comment: The question seems to be that your code and the library code share a pointer to a `T` and use it to access a structure that the `T` is embedded in, and both expect to have their own instance of that structure. That is just wrong. If the library expects to have an `S2` for its own use (even if it is identified by a pointer to a member within it), then it must have made provision for creation of an `S2`, either by doing it itself or by obligating you to do it. Similarly, if you expect to have an `S1`, you must create it and not pass a pointer to one of its members where the library expects…

Comment: … to receive a pointer to a member of an `S2`. Ultimately, the question seems to be “Can I pass a library an argument it does not expect?”, and the answer is no.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have added an example and as per your opinion (and mine as well), there should be no modification of a reconstructed structure if you didn't allocate it.